# Find which capture group a Matcher found a match with

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex with multiple capture groups:

```
String regex = "(first|second|third)|(one|two|three)|(uno|dos|tres)";
```

I can traverse through a `String` finding patterns from each group:

```
String text = "one two uno third second tres";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
for(int index = 0; matcher.find(index); index = matcher.end()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't tell me which group it came from.

I could compare the group found against a `matcher.group(#)` for each group available, then choose whichever one doesn't return `null`:

```
int numOfGroups = 3;
for(int index = 0; matcher.find(index); index = matcher.end()) {
    String result = null;
    int group = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfGroups; i++) {
        String tmp = matcher.group(i);
        if(tmp != null) {
            result = tmp;
            group = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result + " " + group);
}
```

But this increases the time complexity by adding at max another 3 steps (3 groups) per iteration.

How could I determine which group triggered the match?

Comment: Checking which group matched, doesn't add any performance overhead really. There is no magic bullet that gets you the information. For instance, engines aren't smart enough to know you only want to match one group. The important thing (to you) is using it as a flag.

Comment: You can reduce complexity by one by checking only first two groups, if they are both `null`s last group must be the one with match. Other idea could be having separate patterns for each language. This way you will know which pattern you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What about an array of `Matcher`s, one for each `Pattern`?  You wouldn't be identifying which group triggered the match, but which `Matcher` has the matches.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String text = "one two uno third second tres";
    Matcher[] matcher = { 
        Pattern.compile("(first|second|third)").matcher(text),
        Pattern.compile("(one|two|three)").matcher(text),
        Pattern.compile("(uno|dos|tres)").matcher(text)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.length; i++) {
        while (matcher[i].find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher[i].group() + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
third 0
second 0
one 1
two 1
uno 2
tres 2
```